# Simplest form of calculating a weighted score when a,b,c,d are integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is what I have where $a,b,c,d$ are integers with their respective weights multiplied by them.

$$x = (90-(a*.2+b*.3+c*.15+d*.15))/.2$$

This calculates the value of $x$ needed to hit at least a $90$.

I have simplified it to this:

$$x=(450-a-(b*2+c+d)*.75)$$

Can I simplify it any more? Could I remove some integers or combine the math?

Comment: You could remove the unnecessary parentheses around the formula

Comment: @RingØ im talking mathematically here man, but thanks

Comment: Do not vandalize your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "simplify", you mean something like require using only the minimum possible number of basic arithmetic operations (i.e., adding, subtracting, multiplying and/or dividing) to evaluate your expression.

If so, then without any knowledge about the specific values, or properties, of $a$, $b$, $c$ and/or $d$, apart from them being integers, I don't see any way to further "simplify" your updated expression. Although it's not what you're asking for specifically, if you remove the "unnecessary parenthesis around the formula", as [Ring Ø](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3915/ring-%c3%98)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556702/simplest-form-of-calculating-a-weighted-score-when-a-b-c-d-are-integers#comment7313851_3556702) suggests, you then have your minimal expression of

$$x = 450 - a - 0.75(2b + c + d) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note there's also the "equivalent", in terms of # of basic arithmetic operations required, minimal expression of

$$x = 450 - a - 1.5b - 0.75(c + d) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: your assumption is correct, i thought there could be a more minimal expression

Comment: Heyo, could it be further simlified if a,b,c,d could be decimals too?

Comment: @Dr.SuessOfficial Since "simplified" means requiring few basic arithmetic operations, the result doesn't depend on whether or not $a$, $b$, $c$ and/or $d$ are integers or "decimals" (I assume you mean non-integral, e.g., rational). Instead, the only possibility for more simplification is if there were some relationship among them you could use, e.g., that $a = c + d$, in which case my equation ($2$) could be simplified to $x = 450 - 1.75a - 1.5b$.

Comment: okay thx homes, i was just wondering if something like multiplying a weird value of one could reduce it or something I kind of need a,b,c,d to still exist since im inputting them. thanks for da help